# Which Docker versions will K8s 1.7 support?

Tags: kubernetes

1.7 is around the corner according to the [release plan](https://github.com/kubernetes/features/blob/master/release-1.7/release-1.7.md). I'm wondering which Docker versions will be supported. Up until now I got this information from the Changelogs External Dependency Version information paragraph --> https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#external-dependency-version-information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked the same question in the Kubernetes Google Groups and got an official answer.

[According to the sig-node team](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/kubernetes-dev/0_tLFqh0yao/EoU9094dBAAJ) Kubernetes will continue to support only Docker 1.12.x at the launch of Kubernetes 1.7. They will however add 1.13 support early in the lifecycle of K8s 1.7.

Just FYI: Q2 2017 marks the EOL of Docker 1.12 according to their [Maintenance Lifecycle](https://success.docker.com/Policies/Maintenance_Lifecycle)