# Docker version supported in Kubernetes 1.9

Tags: docker, kubernetes

What versions of Docker does Kubernetes `v1.9` support?
Is there a road map for these?

Trend here:

[Docker version supported in Kubernetes 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48400574/docker-version-supported-in-kubernetes-1-8)

[Which Docker versions will K8s 1.7 support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44657320/which-docker-versions-will-k8s-1-7-support)

Answer (score 4):

The validated docker versions are the same as for *v1.8*

- **`1.11.2`** to **`1.13.1`**
- **`17.03.x`**

Source: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.9.md#external-dependencies

Answer (score 2):

The versions supported, according to the source-code, are the following:

- Per OS host version: https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/nodeup/pkg/model/docker.go#L57-L485